# Release Django view at given time

Tags: python, django, django-views

Attempting to write a competition website which will need to release a page at a given time. I could just deploy it at this time manually but this is really not ideal and cannot find anywhere how to do it automatically.

Would it be possible to deploy a view from a given time and then keep it up? If so, how?

Comment: What about check the timestamp on your view ? If < giventime return 404 else return page.html?

Comment: I have tried to do this however by storing challenges as objects and filtering them with release_date__lte = timezone.now() however the post doesn't get released until a few minutes after the given date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found to this problem was to follow [this tutorial](https://djangocentral.com/building-a-blog-application-with-django/) and then change the `queryset` variable to

```py
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Challenge.objects.filter(
            status=1,
            release_date__lte = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc),
        ).order_by('release_date')
```

make sure to import the required packages:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import utc
```

and also make sure to add this function to both `ChallengeList` and `ChallengeDetail`